# Старое значение при keypress/keydown

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Есть вопрос уточнение для детального понимания события клавиши.

Подскажите, если мы запускаем такой код

```html
<input onkeydown="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML=this.value" type="text" placeholder="Вводите символы">
<b></b>
```

То только после второго нажатия начинаем видеть результат.

Но если мы запустим такой код

```html
<input onkeydown="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML= e.key" type="text" placeholder="Вводите символы">
<b></b>
```

То все сработает сразу.

У меня есть предположение, что при первом варианте, значение еще не успело записаться, в `input`. То есть запись в элемент происходит после срабатывания события.

Хотел узнать у более опытных так ли это?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-timing-depth

Answer (score 0):

```js
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  console.log('Нажали, но не отпустили: ' + input.value);
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  console.log('Отпустили: ' + input.value);
});
```

```html
<input id='input' onkeydown="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML=this.value" type="text" placeholder="Вводите символы">
<b></b>
```

Так происходит, потому что на момент нажатия **value** элемента пустой.

Второй пример работает, потому что он возвращается значение нажатой кнопки, которое в момент нажатия(но ещё не отпустили) известно. Ему всё равно, что находится в **value**